# Spectral mapping theorem for constant polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, spectral-theory

Can I prove the spectral mapping theorem fore non-zero constant polynomials?

If $X$ is a complex Banach space and $p$ is any polynomial with complex coefficients and $A$ then how can I show that $\sigma(p(A)) = p(\sigma(A))$?

Basically, I want to show that $\sigma(\alpha I) = \{\alpha\}$ for any complex number $\alpha$?

I have shown that $\{\alpha\}$ $\subset$ $\sigma(\alpha I)$.

How to show the other way round?

Comment: Your last line refers to degree one polynomials, not constant polynomials. And the proof is elementary.

Comment: Edited it..It is I on the left

Comment: I guess you mean $\sigma(aI)=a\sigma(I)$.

Comment: Uhmm...Actually, I think that if polynomial is a constant say a..Then the right hand side should be {a}

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I can't show one side inclusion. Help, please!

Comment: $\alpha I - \lambda I$ is not invertible iff $\lambda=\alpha$. So $\sigma(\alpha I)=\{\alpha\}$.

Comment: Okay.Got it..Thanks!